# Differential privacy and Shamir's scheme

Tags: secret-sharing, differential-privacy

I have been unable to find any proofs (for my own reference) that demonstrate that Shamir's secret sharing scheme does (or does not) satisfy the definition of $\textbf{differential privacy}$ as provided below:

$\mathbb{D}$ denotes the set of possible databases. $\textbf{Q}$ denotes the set of possible queries on the databases. Let $\textbf{M}$ denote a mechanism such that:
\begin{equation}
    \label{mechanism_definition}
    \textbf{M}: \mathbb{D} \times \textbf{Q} \mapsto \mathbb{R}^p
\end{equation}

A mechanism $\textbf{M}$ as defined above is said to satisfy differential privacy if:
\begin{equation}
    \label{differential_privacy_equation}
    \frac{\mathbb{P}[\textbf{M}(D,q) \in S]}{\mathbb{P}[\textbf{M}(D',q) \in S]} = 1 
\end{equation}

$\forall$ D $\in$ $\mathbb{D}$ and $\forall$ q $\in$ $\textbf{Q}$.

$\forall$ S $\subset$ Range ($\textbf{M}$).

[This](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/0a36/6f94baa5c64e26251ff059b91bae00cc0d29.pdf) is the reference I used for the definition provided.

I would appreciate some guidance in this regard.

Comment: Can you cast shamir secret sharing into this framework as an exercise?

Comment: The definition you have given for differential privacy is with privacy parameter $\varepsilon=0$. No interesting algorithms satisfy this definition.